# Jasper update - colums in Table don't export good to docx after update to 6.0.1

Tags: java, jasper-reports, docx, jasperserver

After a JasperServer upgrade (from  5.6 to 6.1), a report with a table that is converted to Docx does not show columns the right way. The strange thing is, it only happens with Docx-export.

When I preview using Java or PDF/RTF export, all goes well. Two pictures describe good/wrong. First one is the right way (in a table like it should) the second one is the unexpected export to Docx.

[image: This is the way it's generated in Java]

[image: And this is what it shows]

Also, the right document has tableGrids and w:hRules like this:

```
<w:gridCol w:w="1280"/>
<w:gridCol w:w="120"/>
(...)
<w:gridCol w:w="3260"/>
<w:gridCol w:w="240"/>
<w:gridCol w:w="1200"/>
```

and

```
 <w:trHeight w:hRule="exact" w:val="1400" />
```

Where the wrong document sais:

```
<w:tblGrid>'
<w:gridCol w:w="1"/>
<w:gridCol w:w="120"/>
(..)
<w:gridCol w:w="3260"/>
<w:gridCol w:w="240"/>
<w:gridCol w:w="1"/>'
```

and

```
 <w:trHeight w:hRule="exact" w:val="0" /
```

Looks like the columns are converted to 1 or so?

**Update: Looks like it's projecting the column-content minus some pixels as you can see in this report**

[image]

Comment: As you probably have the code as unit test, try old and new Jasper libs, and unzip and compare the docx content.xml for layout differences. Seems font related.

Comment: Hi Joop, thanks for your quick reply. But unfortunately that's not the problem. The 2 content.xml's are exactly the same

Comment: And the other XMLs? Sorry, but it must be some tiny detail.

Comment: Hi Joop, thanks again for your quick reply, due to vacation not able to answer earlier. Now comparing both documents, first thing to notice is that the right document contains "<w:vAlign w:val="top" />" much and the new (wrong) document doesn't.

Comment: Also noticed some tblGrid differences, will update in main

Comment: Looks like it smallens the first and last column of a table.. Don't know how! (happens everywhere, so text is cut off etc.)

Comment: It looks like the text font uses exactly 50% of the available space.

Comment: yeah or even 1/3rd of the available space. But it does not do that in Java/RTF output. and I don't know of a place to define that

Comment: Took original JapserFont (SansSerif) but did not solve the problem. It's not only the font, also table width somehow

Comment: @JoopEggen, we eventually downgraded to 6.0.1, problem does not excist there. Thanks for your help!